# Unity2D: Start a new Coroutine whenever a button has been pressed

Tags: button, unity-game-engine

Is there a way how to start a new Coroutine whenever a button has been pressed? I made a script to check how many times a button has been pressed but I don't know how to implement a call which would increment the press count inside the Corutine (buttonCount++). Is it possible?

```
public int buttonCount = 0;

public void Check() {
    buttonCount ++;
}
```

This is what I'm using StartCoroutine  for:

```
public GameObject LeftUp, RightUp, LeftDown, RightDown, ForceSphere;
public int buttonCount = 0;

public void Check() {
    buttonCount ++;
}

public void ActivateForceField ()
{
        StartCoroutine (CreateForceField ()); 
        forceActive = true; 
}

IEnumerator CreateForceField ()
{
    LeftUp.SetActive (true);
    RightUp.SetActive (true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
    LeftDown.SetActive (true);
    RightDown.SetActive (true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
    LeftUp.SetActive (false);
    RightUp.SetActive (false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
    LeftDown.SetActive (false);
    RightDown.SetActive (false);
    //yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
    ForceSphere.SetActive (true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10.0f);
    ForceSphere.SetActive (false);

    forceActive = false;
}
```

I tried putting Check(); in my IEnumerator at the beginning but it didn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: define "it didn't work". What happened? If you got an error, show the entire error message

Comment: Could you a bit more clarify what you would like to achieve? if you put buttonCount++; inside the CreateForceField() it will increment the buttonCount.

Comment: I want to StartCoroutine to however many times I press a button so say like if I press a button 3 times, I want Coroutine to happen only three times and after that it it should happen anymore.

Comment: so just  call the `StartCoroutine (CreateForceField ())`; each time you press the button

Comment: I did but it didn't work, it would continue on after I press the buttons (this is an example) 3 times

Answer (score 1):

for example if your script that contains `ActivateForceField` is called `TheScript` then

create a UI button, in your inspector select your button, then

-look for the button script in the inspector,then

-look for "On click"

-Then select the `gameobject` that contains `TheScript`

-then in the next selection box , select `TheScript` -> `ActivateForceField()`

this way each time your button is clicked this function will be called